# SVG animation resets on hover

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an svg that I animated,

The animation works smoothly, and I have it set to animation-fill-mode: forwards to that it stays put after it’s done animating.

currently, in the svg html, I have

```
stroke="none"
```

and then in the @keyframes css, I have it:

```
from{ stroke: none; }
to { stroke: #fff; }
```

once it’s done animating, I want the strokes to change color on :hover, which it does.

but once I move the cursor away, the animation starts over.

how would I go about making the SVG return right back to it’s #FFF stroke without triggering the animation after the hover is complete?

[Here is my Codepen](https://codepen.io/miguerurso/pen/GOMLLX)

Comment: I just figure I should point out that CSS animations aren't technically supported on SVG, and results will vary incredibly. For instance, in Edge nothing happens at all and all I get is a blank screen.

Comment: CSS animations are the only way to animate in IE/Edge. That nothing happens is probably due to an error.

Comment: You have used a `animation-timing-function: ease`, but there is no smooth transition between values `none` and `#fff` - one is a keyword, the other a color value. What do you want the intermediate values to be?

Comment: @ccprog well, I meant to go from invisible to visible, should I have used rgba values?

Answer (score 2):

You have used a `animation-timing-function: ease`, but there is no smooth transition between values `none` and `#fff` - one is a keyword, the other a color value. For going from "invisible" to "visible", use the `opacity` property instead and define `fill` independent of the animation.

If you do that, you can leave `opacity` at 1 after the animation and only exchange the `fill` value for hovering. Do not turn off the animation during hover.

```
@keyframes shield {
  from {
    opacity: 0; }
  to {
    opacity: 1; } }
#outer-left, #outer-btm-left, #outer-btm-right, #outer-right, #outer-top {
  animation-name: shield;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  stroke:#fff;
  opacity:0;
  }

#outer-left:hover {
  stroke: red;
}

#outer-btm-left:hover {
  stroke: red;
}
```

Comment: that actually seemed to work perfectly! 

Now, another question within the same vicinity, if I wanted to make the whole shape red on hover vs each individual line, how would I got about doing that? 

I tried selecting the svg element and setting the stroke there but it's not working

Comment: Standard CSS rules: selecting elements by their id has a higher specificity than inherited properties. Set the non-hover stroke also on the svg.